# On runtime, why is Android taking XML file from layout instead of layout-large for large Emulators?

Tags: android-layout

I have an XML, `sign.xml` in layout and layout-large. When I run the corresponding activity on large screen emulator `WVGA` ,I am getting the XML from **`layout-large`** and not from layout.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: *When I **run the corresponding activity on large screen emulator ... I am getting the XML from layout-large** and not from layout* Isn't this expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) carefully, you'll get every knowledge regarding your this question.